# iOS App crashes and closes when opened directly from the iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm developing an app with XCode and Objectice-C.

Very often when I run the app directly from the iPhone (not by running it from the XCode), it crashes and closes right away.

What can be the cause and how can I obtain the debug information?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can symbolicate your crashes and leverage [Apteligent](https://www.apteligent.com) 
to obtain extensive crash information.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code it is difficult to say what caused the crash on your iPhone. I have no idea, but I do know that a simulator can behave differently than a real device.

If you reconnect your iPhone to your mac and open the devices window in Xcode, you can obtain a crash log. Go in Xcode to windows>devices and your device window opens. In the left column select the iPhone on which your app crashes. Click on the button "view device logs" and you see a list of logs, including crash logs. If necessary click on All Logs at the top and then select the right crash log.

In the crash log you will see what caused the crash and which threes crashed. To get the most out of your crash log, you have to add your app in iTunes Connect so you can validate and symbolicate your crash logs. This will enable you to see in your code where your app crashed and for what reason.

For more info read the app distribution guide from apple, especially [this section](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AnalyzingCrashReports/AnalyzingCrashReports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH21-SW1).